# É possivel implementar um array dinâmico dentro de uma estrutura em C?

Tags: c, array

Como é possível era criar um array dinâmico dentro de uma estrutura

#### Exemplo

```
typedef struct historico_de_fabrica {
    Hist_id_rolos rolos[1000]; //<- este array em vez de ter 1000 posições queria em
                               //memoria dinâmica para ter um tamanho ajustável ao incremento
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sim. Usa ponteiros e `malloc()`/`realloc()` e `free()`

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), realloc(), free()

struct historico_de_fabrica {
    Hist_id_rolos *rolos;
};

struct historico_de_fabrica obj;
obj.rolos = malloc(1000 * sizeof *obj.rolos);
if (obj.rolos == NULL) /* erro */;
// ...
free(obj.rolos);
```

Se, a meio da execucao, reparares que 1000 posicoes nao te chegam, aumenta o array com `realloc`.

```
if (needmore) {
    Hist_id_rolos *temp;
    temp = realloc(2000 * sizeof *temp);
    if (!temp) /* erro */;
    obj.rolos = temp;
}
```

Comment: Poderia criar funções do tipo `criar_historico(historico_de_fabrica* foo, int size)` para facilitar a criação, edição, redimensionamento de memória, isso torna o código mais reutilizável.

Comment: Outro ponto é que quando o tamanho deixa de ser conhecido, é útil guardar o tamanho do array em uma variável membro.

Comment: Somente como complemento, note que neste caso, a sua struct não terá mais um array, mas sim um ponteiro para uma posição de memória qualquer. Na prática, tome cuidado se fizer "obj2 = obj". Neste caso, "obj2.rolos" e "obj.rolos" irão apontar para o mesmo lugar. Ou seja, se você alterar o valor de "obj.rolos", o valor de "obj2.rolos" também será alterado.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível. E provavelmente é interessante colocar o tamanho que foi alocado junto dentro da `struct`, para uso futuro:

```
typedef struct historico_de_fabrica {
    Hist_id_rolos *rolos;
    size_t tamanho;
} historico_de_fabrica;

// As funções abaixo são sugestões de como implementar uma interface
// para a sua estrutura. Organizar dessa maneira, e só usar as funções
// de interface para acessar a struct, geralmente torna a manutenção
// do código muito mais fácil. Mas cada caso tem que ser avaliado
// se compensa ou não definir as funções de interface.

void alocar_historico_de_fabrica(historico_de_fabrica *hist, size_t tamanho)
{
    hist->rolos = malloc(tamanho * sizeof *hist->rolos);
    hist->tamanho = tamanho;
}

void desalocar_historico_de_fabrica(historico_de_fabrica *hist)
{
    free(hist->rolos);

    // zera o conteúdo de hist, de modo que o ponteiro será NULL,
    // e o tamanho será 0.
    memset(hist, 0, sizeof *hist);
}
```

Então, em algum ponto do código que você precisar usar o array dinâmico, você terá o tamanho junto:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < hist->tamanho; ++i) {
    Hist_id_rolos *elem = &hist->rolos[i];
    // faça alguma coisa com elem...
}
```